# How do I prove $ \lfloor f(n) \rfloor \approx f(n), \forall f:N \rightarrow R$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I prove $ \lfloor f(n) \rfloor \approx f(n), \forall f:N \rightarrow R$? It seems pretty intuitive, but I haven't found a way to express it mathematically.
This question comes from the discrete mathematics course I'm taking, and I believe we're supposed to use the definition of $a(x) \approx b(x)$ as $a(x) = b(x)(1+\varepsilon(x))$, where $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \varepsilon(x) = 0$.
I couldn't find this or a similar proof (searched the textbook, google and stackexchange).

Comment: $f(n)=1.5$ for every $n$ seems to be not true.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by $f(n)+\{f(n)\}$. $\lfloor f(n) \rfloor$ is defined as the biggest integer that is less or equal than $f(n)$ ($f(n)-1 < \lfloor f(n) \rfloor \leq f(n)$)

Comment: $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor+\left\{f(n)\right\}=f(n)$, it's basically saying that $f(n)$ is the sum of it's "integer part" and "fractional part"

Comment: I've been trying to make it true for $f(n)=1.5 \forall n$ but it seems to not be. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the statement is for fucntions which diverges for large $n$. Take the cases when $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) =  \infty$